# Allow sortable item to be dropped in trash, but no sorted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to have a list of news on my site, in the administrator panel. I want to be able to drop items in a trashcan, but not be able to sort the list.
My problem is how to allow it to be dragged to the trashcan and disallow it to be sorted in the list the item is located. It can be dropped in the list, but all items needs to have the same location as before.

**[This is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDZJs/)**

Comment: Add please a code-snippet on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com. It's difficult to understand what really you want.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDZJs/ I dont want to be able to sort them. They should stay in the same order. I only want to be able to trash them.

Comment: @BlackVoid you should know that you can edit your own posts (by clicking the edit link below it). I'll edit your question to include your code, but next time please do it yourself (people often look only at the question and not the comments and they might miss your code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use sortable, and not draggable if you're trying to make something that isn't sortable? Try to make it work with only draggable and a -handle- revert.

Something like this works:

```
$("#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li").draggable({
   revert: true
});

$("#trash").droppable({
  accept: ".connectedSortable li",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
     ui.draggable.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd say this is more suited as a comment, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt :)

Comment: I tried dragable, but if i let go of it, it will not move back to the original position. Ill give it a try again thought.

Answer (score -2):

Sortable is not necessary. The only you need - draggable and droppable. Sorry, but I have not time to fix your example.